# Audio sent from a client to a server

Tags: python, sockets, wave

I've been working all week and I've not got one working model, but what I'm trying to do is take the bytes that had been sent from my client script (which works fine) and save it as a wave file but I cant figure out a way to get the sample width of the audio bytes and save them as a wave file, any help?

Comment: Can you simply send the sample width information separatly? Guessing at it from a protocol-free byte stream is of course extremely tough.

Comment: ive tried to do that, however it still does not work, im quite new to sockets and wave, also im working with a multi client system here so i cant use seperate sockets altogether

Comment: Break it into seprate things, at least concentrate on either wav or sockets. Then break down even further until you are comfortable. Then increase complexity again. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: im alright with them seperatly, its when i put them togeather

Comment: OK. So when you have a large array of bytes, which contain the data as it would arrive from sockets. Then it is simply a WAV problem to solve. If you are alright with that, then you just need to get the info across sockets. If you are not alright then sockets are not part of the problem. Look at the "one array full of some kind of bytes" problem. Can you tell the width? If yes, you also can if the arrays get filled from socket. If you need some additional information, like "the first byte gives the width", then that solution still solves the problem when you transmit via socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your own statement you are comfortable with socket problems and WAV problems separately, but have a problem here where both come together.
A very helpful technique described here: [Eric Lippert: Find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/).

Here is how I would apply the linked technique to your problem:

Consider a large array of bytes, which carry the same information as you transmit via sockets. This makes the whole thing a pure WAV problem. If you can solve that WAV problem, then you just need to apply the solution you find to the data after it arrives via the socket.

If you have trouble solving this pure WAV problem, then stay within WAV area and find out what gets you stuck. Do you need additional information? Maybe a simple width indicator? Where could that indicator be found?
You might want to put it into the first byte. Is the problem solvable now?
If yes then just make sure that the first transmitted byte is the width.